# Bash looping to run a command N times every second

Tags: bash, nested-loops

I am trying to write a code so that a command repeats N(say 10) times every second in bash shell script. I am having problem in making the loop wait for the fraction of second left after sending the 1st 10 commands. I am using while loop to start the loop:

```
while [ $SECONDS -lt $((SECONDS+$time)) ]; do
```

for the number of commands I am using a for loop:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10); do echo 'Hello!'; done
```

Comment: 1. Get current time with nanosecond resolution. 2. Add one second and place it in a variable, ex. `endtime`. 3. Execute the commands in a loop. 4. Calculate difference between current time and endtime. 5. Sleep for that amount of time. 6. Goto step 1.

Comment: Just for the record: `man watch`.

Comment: @Matthieu I was thinking the same, but to my knowledge there is no way to tell watch to stop after the Nth time.

Comment: What about `cron` jobs?

Comment: @Matthieu watch is also working. Thanks

Comment: @PanwenWang I am trying for a load simulator so could not use cron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start a `sleep` in the background and wait for it:

```
sleep 1 &
pid=$!

for i in $(seq 1 10); do echo 'Hello!'; done

wait "$pid"
```

This ensures that the `wait` will only wait for the remainder of the second, regardless of how long the for loop takes. (If it takes longer than 1 second, `wait` finishes immediately).